# How to calculate the adjacent indexes of any given index in a flat (1D) 3D array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a flat 3 dimensional array as such.

`Array[Width*Height*Depth]`

How would I go about calculating, given any valid index within that array, the 6 adjacent indexes?

I would like to be able to call a function that would take in an index and pass out an array that contains the indexes of the adjacent elements.

-------- Edit for clarification

If the array contained 64 elements (`Array[4*4*4]` for example).

If I passed in an index of 0 it would give me back the following indexes as they are adjacent to it if it was a 3dimensional array: `return {1,4,16}`

If I passed in 26 it would return the following: `return {27,25,22,10,42,30}`

Comment: You mean "adjacend" per dimension? (In either x, y _or_ z direction?)

Comment: What are expected to be *adjacent* indexes if location of interest is in the *corner* or *edge*?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I expect them to be empty of course. The return would only pass back valid indexes.